# Losing Lives in c# (Losing 3 lives at once)

Tags: c#, debugging, xna

Basically I have a simple brick breaker game with a paddle a ball and bricks.

I've set the lives up with this code:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        paddle.Update();
        ball.Update();

        foreach (Brick brick in bricks)
        {
            score += brick.CheckCollision(ball);
        }

        ball.PaddleCollision(paddle.GetBounds());

        if (ball.OffBottom())
        {
            --lives;
            if (lives == 0)

                StartGame();
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
    }
```

The problem im getting is that I'm losing 3 lives at once, tweaked this part around alot but still can't get it working.

I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I've just started programming. I've tried Google for C# lives etc. but there's a game called game of lives which keeps coming up and I can't get what I want that way. any help will be appreciated!

Here's the whole method.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) 
{ 

    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit(); 

    paddle.Update(); 
    ball.Update(); 

    foreach (Brick brick in bricks) 
    { 
        score += brick.CheckCollision(ball); 
    } 

    ball.PaddleCollision(paddle.GetBounds()); 

    if (ball.OffBottom()) 
    { 
        --lives; 

        if (lives == 0) 
            StartGame(); 

        base.Update(gameTime); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What event handler is this code inside of? If it's being called three times that handler is almost certainly hooked up more than once.

Comment: There isn't enough information in here to help you. The example section of code doesn't define lives or show the paths of code... Try using FindAllReferences and see what funny thing you're doing.

Comment: Your question is quite vague.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `--lives`, run the debugger, then look at the calling stack.

Comment: Putting breakpoints or logging in the function can give you a better idea of what is happening.  The function is probably getting called 3 times.

Comment: _"i've tried google for c# lives"_ - you're doing it wrong. C# has no notion of a variable named "lives", it just does what you typed: subtract one from a numeric value. Or if you renamed it to "apples", would you search for "C# -3 apples"? You have to set breakpoints and walk through the code (F10, F11) and inspect all interesting variables you see (Watch, QuickWatch, Immediate window) and see what methods get called. I suspect you don't remove the ball from the bottom before checking again, or you call the function this code is in too many times.

Comment: The code is being executed inside of the game update loop, i suspect multiple collisions are occuring, _seemingly_, all at once.

Comment: You are probably reducing `lives` once per game loop, i.e. it is working corectly, but you don't fix where the ball is after losing one life.

Comment: Here's the whole method.

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            paddle.Update();
            ball.Update();

            foreach (Brick brick in bricks)
            {
                score += brick.CheckCollision(ball);
            }

            ball.PaddleCollision(paddle.GetBounds());

            if (ball.OffBottom())
            {
                --lives;
                if (lives == 0)

StartGame();
base.Update(gameTime);
}
}

Comment: @user2291479: You should edit that into your question rather than making it a comment.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett edit was submitted but not approved

Comment: @user2291479: Then you could have waited until we'd approved it. It doesn't take long. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced this problem before, a general solution is: -

- When ball collides with brick > subtract 1 from lives, then...
- ...Start a timer, and set a threshold, say 10 milliseconds
- Then something along the lines of `if ball intersects brick and timer <= threshold, dont subtract from lives`
- Then when timer reaches threshold > reset timer and allow lives to be decremented again

I don't have a code solution unfortunately but this pseudo code is more than enough to solve the problem

Comment: This is a bit of a hack. I would prefer a solution in which you set the object's state as 'collided' and don't change lives again until it has effectively "uncollided and recollided." Setting grace periods simply to work around collision detection problems is messy - unless of course the grace period is because you *actually want a grace period*.

Comment: What does a timer have to do with that? When the ball has collided, you subtract one life. Then you reset the ball position, or you set some (boolean) lock indicating no more lives have to be subtracted until the ball is reset.

Comment: I never said it was pretty ;)

Comment: Thanks Guys, id rep you if i could :D

Comment: Basicly, your problem is due to not resetting position of the ball after removing one life. so the next frame, you will also lose one life. What you need to do is move the ball to a "good" position right after the "--lives;"-line.
Also, I dont agree on the closing of this question. In it's current state, it seems perfectly valid, and this is a common problem.